# Upload canvas element to webserver/database?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm searching for a good method to upload a canvas element from Firefox to a webserver or database to have the ability to reload it later.

My ideas:
1. my first idea was to use getImageData() and save the canvas as an ImageData object to the database, but this might not a good solution because these objets can get quite large.
2. second idea is to use a Flash/Javascript method to upload the canvas as an PNG to the webserver.

Do you have any comments on these methods or maybe have another good solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending canvas.toDataURL() as FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48195480/sending-canvas-todataurl-as-formdata)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvas elements have a `toDataURL` function that serializes the image on the canvas as a PNG, encoded into a [data URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). You could either post the image with a form (by setting a hidden input element's value to the data URL) or in the background using AJAX.

You should be aware that `toDataURL` (or any other method of getting the pixel data) will throw a security exception if the canvas is not "origin-clean". For example, if you ever call `drawImage` with an image from a different domain, you can no longer use the `toDataURL` or `getImageData` functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure I would be worried about size unless images are typically > 10 mb in size. Is that really an issue?

If not, using `getImageData()` would be the most practical and simplest method IMO.