# How to save an HTML5 Canvas as an image on a server?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html5-canvas

I'm working on a generative art project where I would like to allow users to save the resulting images from an algorithm. The general idea is:

- Create an image on an HTML5 Canvas using a generative algorithm
- When the image is completed, allow users to save the canvas as an image file to the server
- Allow the user to either download the image or add it to a gallery of pieces of produced using the algorithm.

However, I’m stuck on the second step. After some help from Google, I found this [blog post](http://permadi.com/blog/2010/10/html5-saving-canvas-image-data-using-php-and-ajax/), which seemed to be exactly what I wanted:

Which led to the JavaScript code:

```
function saveImage() {
  var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

  ajax.open("POST", "testSave.php", false);
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log(ajax.responseText);
  }
  ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/upload");
  ajax.send("imgData=" + canvasData);
}
```

and corresponding PHP (testSave.php):

```
<?php
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"])) {
  $imageData = $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];
  $filteredData = substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",") + 1);
  $unencodedData = base64_decode($filteredData);
  $fp = fopen('/path/to/file.png', 'wb');

  fwrite($fp, $unencodedData);
  fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

But this doesn’t seem to do anything at all.

More Googling turns up this [blog post](http://www.kevinsookocheff.com/2011/07/27/saving-canvas-data-to-an-image-file-with-javascript-and-php/) which is based off of the previous tutorial. Not very different, but perhaps worth a try:

```
$data = $_POST['imgData'];
$file = "/path/to/file.png";
$uri = substr($data,strpos($data, ",") + 1);

file_put_contents($file, base64_decode($uri));
echo $file;
```

This one creates a file (yay) but it’s corrupted and doesn’t seem to contain anything. It also appears to be empty (file size of 0).

Is there anything really obvious that I’m doing wrong? The path where I’m storing my file is writable, so that isn’t an issue, but nothing seems to be happening and I’m not really sure how to debug this.

#### Edit

Following Salvidor Dali’s link I changed the AJAX request to be:

```
function saveImage() {
  var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  var xmlHttpReq = false;

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  ajax.open("POST", "testSave.php", false);
  ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log(ajax.responseText);
  }
  ajax.send("imgData=" + canvasData);
}
```

And now the image file is created and isn’t empty! It seems as if the content type matters and that changing it to `x-www-form-urlencoded` allowed the image data to be sent.

The console returns the (rather large) string of base64 code and the datafile is ~140 kB. However, I still can’t open it and it seems to not be formatted as an image.

Comment: The first blog post your provided uses `ajax.send(canvasData );` while you use it like `ajax.send("imgData="+canvasData);`. Therefore `$GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]` will not be what you expect, you should probably use `$_POST['imgData']`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592164/upload-canvas-element-to-webserver-database

Comment: Diodeus: I'm already using the technique that was suggested in that thread; however, they failed to provide any further details about the implementation and that is where I'm getting stuck.

Comment: When I echo the file information (`$data` in the second php code) all I get returned is a blank line.  Why would that be?  It seems as if perhaps the data being sent isn't correct, but it appears that I'm sending it just like the examples show...

Comment: The PHP code can be simplified and made more robust by using [PHP-FileUpload](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-FileUpload) with its [`DataUriUpload`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-FileUpload/blob/d0065c47dcda18c4965ed900bb15190f7af30e79/src/DataUriUpload.php) component instead. It is [documented here](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-FileUpload/tree/d0065c47dcda18c4965ed900bb15190f7af30e79#data-uri-uploads) and comes with several additional means of validation and enforcing security.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending canvas.toDataURL() as FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48195480/sending-canvas-todataurl-as-formdata)

Answer (score 277, accepted):

Here is an example of how to achieve what you need:

1. **Draw something** (taken from [canvas tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-shape-fill/))

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>

<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // begin custom shape
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(170, 80);
  context.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
  context.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
  context.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
  context.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
  context.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
  context.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);

  // complete custom shape
  context.closePath();
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
  context.fill();
  context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  context.stroke();
</script>
```

2. **Convert canvas image to URL format (base64)**

   ```
       // script

       var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
   ```
3. **Send it to your server via Ajax**

```js
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "script.php",
      data: { 
         imgBase64: dataURL
      }
    }).done(function(o) {
      console.log('saved'); 
      // If you want the file to be visible in the browser 
      // - please modify the callback in javascript. All you
      // need is to return the url to the file, you just saved 
      // and than put the image in your browser.
    });
```

3. **Save base64 on your server as an image** (here is [how to do this in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532993/i-have-a-base64-encoded-png-how-do-i-write-the-image-to-a-file-in-php), the same ideas is in every language. Server side in PHP can be [found here](http://j-query.blogspot.com/2011/02/save-base64-encoded-canvas-image-to-png.html)):

Comment: I mean that the file is there but it doesn't open in my browser or any image viewer if I download it.

Comment: `You send it to your server as an ajax request` does this method require user's confirming? Or I can silently send image from canvas to server?

Comment: I get an error on Web Console. [16:53:43.227] SecurityError: The operation is insecure. @ http://sharevi.com/staging/canvas.html:43 the This connection is insecure. Is there something that needs to be done?/// UPDATE I think i know why, i was using cross domain images

Comment: but alpha is 0 which makes it no-fill, that is completely transparent. no matter what the first three value is.

Answer (score 75):

I played with this two weeks ago, it's very simple. The only problem is that all the tutorials just talk about saving the image locally. This is how I did it:

1) I set up a form so I can use a POST method.

2) When the user is done drawing, he can click the "Save" button.

3) When the button is clicked I take the image data and put it into a hidden field. After that I submit the form.

```
document.getElementById('my_hidden').value = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
document.forms["form1"].submit();
```

4) When the form is submited I have this small php script:

```
<?php 
$upload_dir = somehow_get_upload_dir();  //implement this function yourself
$img = $_POST['my_hidden'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = $upload_dir."image_name.png";
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
header('Location: '.$_POST['return_url']);
?>
```

Comment: is it ok to if I use canvas.toDataURL()? I have dynamic file extension, like jpeg, png, gif. I tried canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg') but it is not working. What's wrong?

Comment: I was getting 413 (request too large) error trying to send image from canvas by AJAX. Then this approach helped me get the images through.

Comment: Any reason this one is giving me a 0kb png file?

Comment: For jpg you would need to do **canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg')** - at least thats what did it for me on Chrome.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed :D

Comment: Great solution. Posted data are also good for showing an image in the target page:
echo '<img src="' . $_POST['my_hidden'] . '">';

Answer (score 34):

I think you should convert the image to base64 and then to Blob and send it to the server. When you use base64 images, a lot of lines will be sent to server. With blob, it's only the file.

You can use this code bellow:

```js
function dataURLtoBlob(dataURL) {
  let array, binary, i, len;
  binary = atob(dataURL.split(',')[1]);
  array = [];
  i = 0;
  len = binary.length;
  while (i < len) {
    array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
    i++;
  }
  return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {
    type: 'image/png'
  });
};
```

And canvas code here:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const file = dataURLtoBlob( canvas.toDataURL() );
```

After that you can use ajax with Form:

```js
const fd = new FormData;

fd.append('image', file);

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/url-to-save',
  data: fd,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false
});
```

---

> The code in [**CoffeeScript**](https://coffeescript.org/) syntax:

```coffee
dataURLtoBlob = (dataURL) ->
  # Decode the dataURL
  binary = atob(dataURL.split(',')[1])
  # Create 8-bit unsigned array
  array = []
  i = 0
  while i < binary.length
    array.push binary.charCodeAt(i)
    i++
  # Return our Blob object
  new Blob([ new Uint8Array(array) ], type: 'image/png')
```

And canvas code here:

```coffee
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
file = dataURLtoBlob(canvas.toDataURL())
```

After that you can use ajax with Form:

```coffee
fd = new FormData
# Append our Canvas image file to the form data
fd.append 'image', file
$.ajax
  type: 'POST'
  url: '/url-to-save'
  data: fd
  processData: false
  contentType: false
```

Comment: It's possible to directly convert a canvas to a blob by simply using: canvas.toBlob. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob

Comment: Thank you @Felipe, I will update it soon when I test with my current demo.

Answer (score 16):

Send canvas image to PHP:

```js
var photo = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');                
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'photo_upload.php',
  data: {
    photo: photo
  }
});
```

Here's PHP script:
`photo_upload.php`

```php
<?php

    $data = $_POST['photo'];
    list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
    list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
    $data = base64_decode($data);

    mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/photos");

    file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/photos/".time().'.png', $data);
    die;
?>
```

Answer (score 12):

I've worked on something similar.
Had to convert canvas **Base64-encoded** image to `Uint8Array Blob`.

```
function b64ToUint8Array(b64Image) {
   var img = atob(b64Image.split(',')[1]);
   var img_buffer = [];
   var i = 0;
   while (i < img.length) {
      img_buffer.push(img.charCodeAt(i));
      i++;
   }
   return new Uint8Array(img_buffer);
}

var b64Image = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
var u8Image  = b64ToUint8Array(b64Image);

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("image", new Blob([ u8Image ], {type: "image/jpg"}));

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/api/upload", true);
xhr.send(formData);
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to save data that is derived from a Javascript `canvas.toDataURL()` function, you have to convert blanks into plusses. If you do not do that, the decoded data is corrupted:

```
<?php
  $encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$encodedData);
  $decocedData = base64_decode($encodedData);
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/ro/function.base64-decode.php

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Salvador Dali's answer:

on the server side don't forget that the data comes in base64 **string** format. It's important because in some programming languages you need to explisitely say that this string should be regarded as **bytes** not simple Unicode string.

Otherwise decoding won't work: the image will be saved but it will be an unreadable file.

Answer (score 0):

I just made an imageCrop and Upload feature with

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-crop

to get the ImagePreview ( the cropped image rendering in a canvas)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob

```
canvas.toBlob(function(blob){...}, 'image/jpeg', 0.95);
```

I prefer sending data in blob with content type `image/jpeg` rather than `toDataURL` ( a huge base64 string`

My implementation for uploading to Azure Blob using SAS URL

```
axios.post(azure_sas_url, image_in_blob, {
   headers: {
      'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
      'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
   }
})
```