# saving a canvas image to the server

Tags: image, canvas, save

I'm trying to save a canvas image to the web page server, so a php script can post it to a web api. I've been looking around and all I see is saving it in the users web browser, any help for a newbie?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the contents of the canvas as a data url using the [toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement) method, and then upload this to your server using an AJAX POST.

The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198131/how-to-save-a-html5-canvas-as-image-on-a-server) should give you some help.