# face detection and save image

Tags: javascript, canvas, face-detection

I'm working on a project that will use a user's webcam and always be looking for faces when detected and the face is within a certain area (to make sure that they are facing forward). And then take a picture of the face and save it to the web server.

I've found some facial detection projects that use usergermedia and use a canvas to overlay an image on top of the detected face seen here: 
https://github.com/neave/face-detection

The code is confusing to a newbie like me, I see that I should probably play with the face.html file and the detect objects function. But instead of having it draw the glasses how would I get it to save it as an image?

Comment: Could someone explain more on this:       stackoverflow.com/questions/13198131/how-to-save-a-html5-canvas-as-image-on-a-server

Answer (score 3):

You could use the canvas element method [toDataURL()](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-url/) to extract the image bitmap decoded into base64 and send it to your server. There you can decode the base64 string and save the content into a new file or you can use a graphic library (depending on your server and programming language of choice) to manipulate the bitmap before saving it into an image file.

This can help you: [How to save a HTML5 Canvas as Image on a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198131/how-to-save-a-html5-canvas-as-image-on-a-server)

Comment: Aha, I found this related to his question: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/