# Trying to convert html div to image. Taking into account transform3d

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2canvas

I already looked at [How do I convert my entire div data into image and save it into directory without using canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545034/how-do-i-convert-my-entire-div-data-into-image-and-save-it-into-directory-withou)

And I used the html2canvas library and i was able to get an image, but it was not how i wanted it because I had a 3dtransfomed div inside and the final image did not keep that property.

The result using the html2canvas lib was this:
[image]

And what I wanna get is something like this (blue dots are irrelevant):
[image]

I have lets say this html code: `<div id=background><div id=pig style=transform: matrix3d(1,2,4,2,34,4,5,3,54,3,4,4)><img src=whatever/></div></div>`  And I want to convert it to an image. I tried using the html2canvas library that they mentioned on the post i linked to at the top. But the result was the first image i posted. What I want the result to look like is the second image. So I thought it was because it did not take into account the transform3d on the pig div.

Comment: I am unsure of what you are actually asking here..

Comment: @niemmi I have lets say this html code: `<div id=background><div id=pig><img src=whatever/></div></div> ` And I want to convert it to an image. I tried using the html2canvas library that they mentioned on the post i linked to at the top. But the result was the first image i posted.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know anything about the subject, I just embedded the images to make it easier to read. If you have additional information please  edit the original question.

Comment: @RhysBradbury I added some more info at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend taking the image you get (which looks fine, but not skewed correctly) and running it through CSS transformations.

[Information about CSS 3D Transforms](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_3dtransforms.asp)

[This demo of skewing a 3D prism with CSS](https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/rectangular-prism.html) should be of particular interest to you