# Edit picture on the web and export as image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey I wonder where can I find a tool to edit image online. I want to create a tool that I give some text & an image which will write it(the text) on a specific place in the image, and allow for saving or exporting the result as jpg or png.

Comment: Maybe take a look at `canvas`? For example `toDataURL('image/png')`.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Questions about tools and software for a specific purpose are off-topic here. However, I won't flag it because @John mentioned a native solution to your problem. Have a good stay with us !

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer for [Put text on an image and save as image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770039/put-text-on-an-image-and-save-as-image) explains how to do this:

```
window.onload = function(){
 var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
 var imageObj = new Image();
 imageObj.onload = function(){
     context.drawImage(imageObj, 10, 10);
     context.font = "20px Calibri";
     context.fillText("My TEXT!", 50, 200);

     // open the image in a new browser tab
     // the user can right-click and save that image
     var win=window.open();
     win.document.write("<img src='"+canvas.toDataURL()+"'/>");    

 };
 imageObj.src = "mail-image.jpg"; 
};
```

You can learn more about canvas [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp)