# Unable to get correct image when converting SVG to PNG using Imagick

Tags: javascript, php, svg, imagemagick, svg.js

I've got SVG HTML code generated by `svg.js` library. Using PHP's `Imagick` I want to convert SVG HTML to PNG.

PHP:

```
$svg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><svg id="SvgjsSvg2552" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="1500" height="1500" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><g id="SvgjsG2676"><g id="SvgjsG2554"><g id="SvgjsG2555"><g id="SvgjsG2556"><g id="SvgjsG2557"><path id="SvgjsPath2558" d="M665 100L665 167.0881805419922 " stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1" fill="none"></path><path id="SvgjsPath2559" d="M715 100L715 176.7947235107422 " stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#a80fa8" stroke-width="10" fill="none"></path></g><g id="SvgjsG2560"><path id="SvgjsPath2561" d="M565 85L565 176.7947235107422 " stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="23" fill="none"></path><path id="SvgjsPath2562" d="M615 85L615 167.0881805419922 " stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1" fill="none"></path></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2563"><g id="SvgjsG2564" transform="rotate(210 640 429.5)"><path id="SvgjsPath2565" d="M665 100L665 167.0881805419922 " stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#a80fa8" stroke-width="2.3" fill="none"></path><path id="SvgjsPath2566" d="M715 100L715 176.7947235107422 " stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="23" fill="none"></path></g><g id="SvgjsG2567" transform="rotate(210 640 429.5)"><path id="SvgjsPath2568" d="M565 85L565 176.7947235107422 " stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#a80fa8" stroke-width="10" fill="none"></path><path id="SvgjsPath2569" d="M615 85L615 167.0881805419922 " stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#a80fa8" stroke-width="2.3" fill="none"></path></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2570"><g id="SvgjsG2571"><path id="SvgjsPath2572" d="M565 176.7947235107422Q565.4104614257812 408.6929016113281 448.6954650878906 610.8491821289062 " stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="23" fill="none"></path><path id="SvgjsPath2573" d="M615 167.0881805419922A200 200 0 0 0 665 167.0881805419922 " stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1" fill="none"></path></g><g id="SvgjsG2574"><path id="SvgjsPath2575" d="M578.5992431640625 685.8491821289062Q715.380615234375 448.93695068359375 715 176.7947235107422 " stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#a80fa8" stroke-width="10" fill="none"></path><path id="SvgjsPath2576" d="M530.4447021484375 669.2553100585938A200 200 0 0 0 487.1434631347656 644.2553100585938 " stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#a80fa8" stroke-width="2.3" fill="none"></path></g></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2577"><g id="SvgjsG2578" transform="translate(540 25)"><g id="SvgjsG2579"><rect id="SvgjsRect2580" width="200" height="15" fill="none" stroke-width="0"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2581" font-family="arial" x="100" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2582" dy="0.9em" x="100">1</tspan></text></g><g id="SvgjsG2583" transform="translate(0 15)"><g id="SvgjsG2584"><rect id="SvgjsRect2585" width="200" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2586" font-family="arial" x="100" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2587" dy="0.9em" x="100">352</tspan></text></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2588" transform="translate(0 30)"><g id="SvgjsG2589"><rect id="SvgjsRect2590" width="100" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2591" font-family="arial" x="50" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2592" dy="0.9em" x="50">251</tspan></text></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2593" transform="translate(0 45)"><g id="SvgjsG2594"><g id="SvgjsG2595"><rect id="SvgjsRect2596" width="50" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2597" font-family="arial" x="25" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2598" dy="0.9em" x="25">250</tspan></text></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2599" transform="translate(50 0)"><g id="SvgjsG2600"><rect id="SvgjsRect2601" width="50" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2602" font-family="arial" x="25" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2603" dy="0.9em" x="25">1</tspan></text></g></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2604" transform="translate(100 30)"><g id="SvgjsG2605"><rect id="SvgjsRect2606" width="100" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2607" font-family="arial" x="50" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2608" dy="0.9em" x="50">101</tspan></text></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2609" transform="translate(100 45)"><g id="SvgjsG2610"><g id="SvgjsG2611"><rect id="SvgjsRect2612" width="50" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2613" font-family="arial" x="25" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2614" dy="0.9em" x="25">1</tspan></text></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2615" transform="translate(50 0)"><g id="SvgjsG2616"><rect id="SvgjsRect2617" width="50" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2618" font-family="arial" x="25" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2619" dy="0.9em" x="25">100</tspan></text></g></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2620" transform="translate(0 60)"><polygon id="SvgjsPolygon2621" points="0,0 50,15 100,0" fill="#000000" stroke="#" stroke-width="0.1"></polygon></g><g id="SvgjsG2622" transform="translate(100 60)"><polygon id="SvgjsPolygon2623" points="0,15 50,0 100,15" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1"></polygon></g><g id="SvgjsG2624" transform="translate(0 75)"></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2627" transform="rotate(210 640 429.5) translate(540 25)"><g id="SvgjsG2628"><rect id="SvgjsRect2629" width="200" height="15" fill="none" stroke-width="0"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2630" font-family="arial" x="100" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(180 100 7.6015625)"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2631" dy="0.9em" x="100">2</tspan></text></g><g id="SvgjsG2632" transform="translate(0 15)"><g id="SvgjsG2633"><rect id="SvgjsRect2634" width="200" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2635" font-family="arial" x="100" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(180 100 7.6015625)"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2636" dy="0.9em" x="100">396</tspan></text></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2637" transform="translate(0 30)"><g id="SvgjsG2638"><rect id="SvgjsRect2639" width="100" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2640" font-family="arial" x="50" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(180 50 7.6015625)"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2641" dy="0.9em" x="50">123</tspan></text></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2642" transform="translate(0 45)"><g id="SvgjsG2643"><g id="SvgjsG2644"><rect id="SvgjsRect2645" width="50" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2646" font-family="arial" x="25" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(180 25 7.6015625)"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2647" dy="0.9em" x="25">100</tspan></text></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2648" transform="translate(50 0)"><g id="SvgjsG2649"><rect id="SvgjsRect2650" width="50" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2651" font-family="arial" x="25" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(180 25 7.6015625)"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2652" dy="0.9em" x="25">23</tspan></text></g></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2653" transform="translate(100 30)"><g id="SvgjsG2654"><rect id="SvgjsRect2655" width="100" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2656" font-family="arial" x="50" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(180 50 7.6015625)"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2657" dy="0.9em" x="50">273</tspan></text></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2658" transform="translate(100 45)"><g id="SvgjsG2659"><g id="SvgjsG2660"><rect id="SvgjsRect2661" width="50" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2662" font-family="arial" x="25" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(180 25 7.6015625)"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2663" dy="0.9em" x="25">23</tspan></text></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2664" transform="translate(50 0)"><g id="SvgjsG2665"><rect id="SvgjsRect2666" width="50" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2667" font-family="arial" x="25" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(180 25 7.6015625)"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2668" dy="0.9em" x="25">250</tspan></text></g></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2669" transform="translate(0 60)"><polygon id="SvgjsPolygon2670" points="0,0 50,15 100,0" fill="#000000" stroke="#a80fa8" stroke-width="0.1"></polygon></g><g id="SvgjsG2671" transform="translate(100 60)"><polygon id="SvgjsPolygon2672" points="0,15 50,0 100,15" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1"></polygon></g><g id="SvgjsG2673" transform="translate(0 75)"></g></g></g></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2677" transform="rotate(120 1195 47.5) translate(1180 10)"><polygon id="SvgjsPolygon2678" points="15,0 7.5,15 22.5,15" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1"></polygon><ellipse id="SvgjsEllipse2679" rx="15" ry="15" cx="15" cy="45" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1"></ellipse><path id="SvgjsPath2680" d="M15 15L15 75 " stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1"></path></g></svg>';
    $imagick = new \Imagick();
    $imagick->readimageblob($svg);
    $imagick->setimageformat('png32');
    $imagick->writeimage(WWW_DIR . '/files/12.png');
    $imagick->clear();
    $imagick->destroy();
```

SVG:

```
<svg id="SvgjsSvg2552" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="1500" height="1500" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><g id="SvgjsG2676"><g id="SvgjsG2554"><g id="SvgjsG2555"><g id="SvgjsG2556"><g id="SvgjsG2557"><path id="SvgjsPath2558" d="M665 100L665 167.0881805419922 " stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1" fill="none"></path><path id="SvgjsPath2559" d="M715 100L715 176.7947235107422 " stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#a80fa8" stroke-width="10" fill="none"></path></g><g id="SvgjsG2560"><path id="SvgjsPath2561" d="M565 85L565 176.7947235107422 " stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="23" fill="none"></path><path id="SvgjsPath2562" d="M615 85L615 167.0881805419922 " stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1" fill="none"></path></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2563"><g id="SvgjsG2564" transform="rotate(210 640 429.5)"><path id="SvgjsPath2565" d="M665 100L665 167.0881805419922 " stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#a80fa8" stroke-width="2.3" fill="none"></path><path id="SvgjsPath2566" d="M715 100L715 176.7947235107422 " stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="23" fill="none"></path></g><g id="SvgjsG2567" transform="rotate(210 640 429.5)"><path id="SvgjsPath2568" d="M565 85L565 176.7947235107422 " stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#a80fa8" stroke-width="10" fill="none"></path><path id="SvgjsPath2569" d="M615 85L615 167.0881805419922 " stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#a80fa8" stroke-width="2.3" fill="none"></path></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2570"><g id="SvgjsG2571"><path id="SvgjsPath2572" d="M565 176.7947235107422Q565.4104614257812 408.6929016113281 448.6954650878906 610.8491821289062 " stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="23" fill="none"></path><path id="SvgjsPath2573" d="M615 167.0881805419922A200 200 0 0 0 665 167.0881805419922 " stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1" fill="none"></path></g><g id="SvgjsG2574"><path id="SvgjsPath2575" d="M578.5992431640625 685.8491821289062Q715.380615234375 448.93695068359375 715 176.7947235107422 " stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#a80fa8" stroke-width="10" fill="none"></path><path id="SvgjsPath2576" d="M530.4447021484375 669.2553100585938A200 200 0 0 0 487.1434631347656 644.2553100585938 " stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#a80fa8" stroke-width="2.3" fill="none"></path></g></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2577"><g id="SvgjsG2578" transform="translate(540 25)"><g id="SvgjsG2579"><rect id="SvgjsRect2580" width="200" height="15" fill="none" stroke-width="0"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2581" font-family="arial" x="100" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2582" dy="0.9em" x="100">1</tspan></text></g><g id="SvgjsG2583" transform="translate(0 15)"><g id="SvgjsG2584"><rect id="SvgjsRect2585" width="200" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2586" font-family="arial" x="100" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2587" dy="0.9em" x="100">352</tspan></text></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2588" transform="translate(0 30)"><g id="SvgjsG2589"><rect id="SvgjsRect2590" width="100" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2591" font-family="arial" x="50" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2592" dy="0.9em" x="50">251</tspan></text></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2593" transform="translate(0 45)"><g id="SvgjsG2594"><g id="SvgjsG2595"><rect id="SvgjsRect2596" width="50" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2597" font-family="arial" x="25" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2598" dy="0.9em" x="25">250</tspan></text></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2599" transform="translate(50 0)"><g id="SvgjsG2600"><rect id="SvgjsRect2601" width="50" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2602" font-family="arial" x="25" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2603" dy="0.9em" x="25">1</tspan></text></g></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2604" transform="translate(100 30)"><g id="SvgjsG2605"><rect id="SvgjsRect2606" width="100" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2607" font-family="arial" x="50" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2608" dy="0.9em" x="50">101</tspan></text></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2609" transform="translate(100 45)"><g id="SvgjsG2610"><g id="SvgjsG2611"><rect id="SvgjsRect2612" width="50" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2613" font-family="arial" x="25" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2614" dy="0.9em" x="25">1</tspan></text></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2615" transform="translate(50 0)"><g id="SvgjsG2616"><rect id="SvgjsRect2617" width="50" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2618" font-family="arial" x="25" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2619" dy="0.9em" x="25">100</tspan></text></g></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2620" transform="translate(0 60)"><polygon id="SvgjsPolygon2621" points="0,0 50,15 100,0" fill="#000000" stroke="#" stroke-width="0.1"></polygon></g><g id="SvgjsG2622" transform="translate(100 60)"><polygon id="SvgjsPolygon2623" points="0,15 50,0 100,15" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1"></polygon></g><g id="SvgjsG2624" transform="translate(0 75)"></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2627" transform="rotate(210 640 429.5) translate(540 25)"><g id="SvgjsG2628"><rect id="SvgjsRect2629" width="200" height="15" fill="none" stroke-width="0"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2630" font-family="arial" x="100" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(180 100 7.6015625)"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2631" dy="0.9em" x="100">2</tspan></text></g><g id="SvgjsG2632" transform="translate(0 15)"><g id="SvgjsG2633"><rect id="SvgjsRect2634" width="200" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2635" font-family="arial" x="100" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(180 100 7.6015625)"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2636" dy="0.9em" x="100">396</tspan></text></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2637" transform="translate(0 30)"><g id="SvgjsG2638"><rect id="SvgjsRect2639" width="100" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2640" font-family="arial" x="50" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(180 50 7.6015625)"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2641" dy="0.9em" x="50">123</tspan></text></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2642" transform="translate(0 45)"><g id="SvgjsG2643"><g id="SvgjsG2644"><rect id="SvgjsRect2645" width="50" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2646" font-family="arial" x="25" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(180 25 7.6015625)"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2647" dy="0.9em" x="25">100</tspan></text></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2648" transform="translate(50 0)"><g id="SvgjsG2649"><rect id="SvgjsRect2650" width="50" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2651" font-family="arial" x="25" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(180 25 7.6015625)"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2652" dy="0.9em" x="25">23</tspan></text></g></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2653" transform="translate(100 30)"><g id="SvgjsG2654"><rect id="SvgjsRect2655" width="100" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2656" font-family="arial" x="50" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(180 50 7.6015625)"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2657" dy="0.9em" x="50">273</tspan></text></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2658" transform="translate(100 45)"><g id="SvgjsG2659"><g id="SvgjsG2660"><rect id="SvgjsRect2661" width="50" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2662" font-family="arial" x="25" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(180 25 7.6015625)"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2663" dy="0.9em" x="25">23</tspan></text></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2664" transform="translate(50 0)"><g id="SvgjsG2665"><rect id="SvgjsRect2666" width="50" height="15" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.2"></rect><text id="SvgjsText2667" font-family="arial" x="25" y="0" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" font-stretch="narrower" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(180 25 7.6015625)"><tspan id="SvgjsTspan2668" dy="0.9em" x="25">250</tspan></text></g></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2669" transform="translate(0 60)"><polygon id="SvgjsPolygon2670" points="0,0 50,15 100,0" fill="#000000" stroke="#a80fa8" stroke-width="0.1"></polygon></g><g id="SvgjsG2671" transform="translate(100 60)"><polygon id="SvgjsPolygon2672" points="0,15 50,0 100,15" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1"></polygon></g><g id="SvgjsG2673" transform="translate(0 75)"></g></g></g></g></g><g id="SvgjsG2677" transform="rotate(120 1195 47.5) translate(1180 10)"><polygon id="SvgjsPolygon2678" points="15,0 7.5,15 22.5,15" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1"></polygon><ellipse id="SvgjsEllipse2679" rx="15" ry="15" cx="15" cy="45" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1"></ellipse><path id="SvgjsPath2680" d="M15 15L15 75 " stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1"></path></g></svg>
```

This is what I get. Picture on the left (taken from browser) is a desired state. Magick's not happening :)

[image]

I have tried simplier SVG HTML code and it worked. Is there anything wrong with the generated SVG HTML code? I've validated the generated SVG and no errors where found.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If possible, you can convert the SVG to an image directly in the browser. Here are some ruff example code you can take a look at: https://gist.github.com/otm/379a3cdb572ac81d8c19

Comment: Thank for comment. I've tried it but got strange error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: text is not defined VM402:1`. I have no idea what `VM402:1` is. Google didn't find it as well. Do I need any kind of special, e.g. JS, library?

Comment: Please make a fiddle, the "VM" errors are from the browser. The example is in Native JS, so no library is needed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ErG8h/ - but I'm able to recall that error in jsfiddle. I'll post a screen.

Comment: Here is screenshot. http://i.imgur.com/8Y7QwBp.png

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ErG8h/1/
I will write up an proper answer as soon as possible.

Comment: Wow, nice, thanks a lot. Is it posible to save that image to HDD on server?

Comment: There is an example on stackoverflow, I have not tried it though, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198131/how-to-save-a-html5-canvas-as-image-on-a-server

Comment: Can you donwnload that image from fiddle? Using browser's "Save image as...". I get no file error.

Comment: No, you have to do it with JS, or send the image to the server.

Comment: Well I have tried that example to send base64 code to server using AJAX and then save it as a file using `file_put_contents`. File was corrupted. However, I am quite confused by the `canvas` thing. My image source starts with `blob:` but others have `data:image/png;base64`. I've tried to generate image source using `canvas.toDataURL("image/png");` but only got empty image. I think I'm missing something but don't know what.

Comment: I've been playing around with `canvas`, but I don't think it can handle whole complex svg properly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the best way to export svg is to use the Inkscape executable. We have been using it in production for the past five years and it is rock solid. On a mac we approach Inkscape like this to export a png:

```
/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/script filename.svg --export-png=filename.png
```

We have tested a lot of svg parsers and none of them did so well as Inkscape. Together with the [svg export plugin](https://github.com/wout/svg.export.js) for [svg.js](http://svgjs.dev/) it works brilliantly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. I'm using Inkscape and must agree that it now far the best option I've found. But there is one problem with text vertical position. Hope I can fix it using export plugin with some "export-only rule".

Comment: That is already possible by using the `exportAttr()` method. This will modify the defined attributes only on export: https://github.com/wout/svg.export.js#export-attributes

Comment: Yes, I was pointing to that by saying "export-only" :) But one more thing matters to me now. How can I export `image` http://documentup.com/wout/svg.js#image? Do I need to specify absolute path?

Comment: Yes indeed, you'll have to export with `xlink:href="/absolute/path/to/image.jpg"`.

Answer (score 1):

The issues you're experiencing are related SVG 1.1 features that are not fully supported by ImageMagick's internal SVG sub-process. Specifically the `font-stretch="narrower"` attribute, and the nested path grouping of `g` elements. The best fix would be to install the [RSVG](https://developer.gnome.org/rsvg/stable/) delegate & confirm by running the following...

```
identify -list format
# or
identify -list delegate
```

Another option would be to re-evaluate how your generating the SVG. Tools like [svg.js](http://svgjs.com/) are easy & lightwight, but the generated output may be very complex with unnecessary elements & transformations. ImageMagick also supports [SVG path specs](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#paths). You may be able to generate the images directly in PHP-Imagick.

Comment: Thanks a reply. I've read about the RSVG delegate but haven't found tutorial how to install that on Windows, only this link http://cairographics.org/download/. To "ease" my SVG I have to get rid off `font-stretch` and nested groups?

Comment: I have installed `Python RSVG` https://github.com/jmcb/python-rsvg-dependencies on my Windows machine but using `convert -list format` there is still `SVG  SVG       rw+   Scalable Vector Graphics (XML 2.9.0)`