# method to save file in html?

Tags: javascript, html, webserver, centos7

So I have been messing around with HTML and [Literally Canvas](http://literallycanvas.com/index.html), which basically just creates a drawing board for you, and got it so I have an export button on my page. When you hit this button it currently only opens a new page with the image; what I want to accomplish is have it save the file locally on my webserver when someone hits the button.

The line that opens the drawing is:

```
      window.open(lc.getImage().toDataURL());
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Here's my full code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- stylesheet -->
    <link href="/draw/literallycanvas-0.4.1/css/literallycanvas.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- dependency: React.js -->
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.10.0/react-with-addons.js"></script>

    <!-- Literally Canvas -->
    <script src="/draw/literallycanvas-0.4.1/js/literallycanvas.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- where the widget goes. you can do CSS to it. -->


    <!-- kick it off -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></src>
    <script>
        // Look ma, no jQuery!
        LC.init(
            document.getElementsByClassName('literally')[0],
            {imageURLPrefix: '/draw/literallycanvas-0.4.1/lib/img'}
        );

        /* or if you just love jQuery,
            $('.literally').literallycanvas({imageURLPrefix: '/draw/literallycanvas-0.4.1/lib/img'})
        */


    </script>


<div class="literally export"></div>
<form class="controls export">
  <input type="submit" data-action="export-as-png" value="Export as PNG">
</form>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var lc = LC.init(document.getElementsByClassName('literally export')[0]);
    $('.controls.export [data-action=export-as-png]').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.open(lc.getImage().toDataURL());
    });
  });
</script>





  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save a HTML5 Canvas as Image on a server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198131/how-to-save-a-html5-canvas-as-image-on-a-server)

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to save the image to your webserver, as everything is on the client side. Your best bet would be to upload the image after getting the dataUrl. This question shows how to do that: [How to save a HTML5 Canvas as Image on a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198131/how-to-save-a-html5-canvas-as-image-on-a-server)