# save canvas image to server

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

I'm trying to save the canvas image to the server.  I can save the file, but it's always 0 bytes.  What's wrong with my code?

```
<script>
function test(){
var canvas  = document.getElementById("cvs");
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "upload.php",
  data: { 
     imgBase64: dataURL
  }
}).done(function(o) {
  console.log('saved'); 

});

}
</script>
```

php:

```
<?php    
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'uploads/');
$img = $_POST['img'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
?>
```

Comment: Where do you paint to your canvas

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198131/how-to-save-a-html5-canvas-as-image-on-a-server

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean.  I paint it on the same page as the javascript above.

Comment: That's the link where I figured out how to get what I have.  The problem is, when I follow those directions, I get the 0 bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you have to be sure that you have painted to the canvas **after** you defined the `canvas` variable and **before** you created the `dataURL`

Second, it seems like you are looking for `img` in this php line:

```
$img = $_POST['img'];
```

but in your javascript you are defining it as `imgBase64` in:

```
data: { 
   imgBase64: dataURL
}
```

lastly you should be adding `console.log(dataURL)` after the `dataURL` has been created to be sure that there is anything in it.

Comment: Thanks.  The problem was fixed when I replaced 'img' with 'imgBase64' as you suggested.  I had tried to plug in 'dataUrl' but that wasn't working.  Also, I had console.log(dataURL) in my code before posting, but took it out.