# Record audio and save to a location.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to record audio and save to a location.

I google for this but I get some links which are not working. and some of them I downloaded and tested but no luck.

I can use HTML5, PHP, javascript, jquery for this.

I think someone can help me to suggest some working links.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220859/record-audio-from-user-and-save-to-server may help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413063/html5-record-audio-to-file

Comment: You can use ```MediaRecorder API ``` for this. Ref - https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/mediarecorder

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Make an effort to solve the problem. If you run into a specific issue doing so, post a question with your attempt (including all the relevant code), saying what isn't working, and explaining your research so far.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish that is by using webrtc. https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/

remember that this requires https when uploaded on live server.