# getting html canvas image as javascript object

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to get html canvas image as javascript object. I looked samples from internet. But all samples are getting images from a source to canvas like [this](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/):

```
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var imageObj = new Image();

      imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 50);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
    </script>
  </body>
```

But my problem: There is an image on canvas element that created by pencil. I want to get that image as object and post to server. But I could not get.

Comment: The image created by pencil is the drawImage result, or something user can create afterwards?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save a HTML5 Canvas as Image on a server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198131/how-to-save-a-html5-canvas-as-image-on-a-server)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `canvas.toDataURL()`?

more hardcore way might be `canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData()` would return ImageData object.

Comment: `canvas.toDataURL` is correct. **And to give an explanation:** toDataURL will convert the canvas into a dataURL string. Unlike objects, strings are easy to transmit and save. The .toDataURL string can be sent to the server and saved in your server file system or database. A common way to send the string is to use jQuery's AJAX method to POST the string to a url on your server that knows how to save that string.