# fengyuanchen jQuery cropper plugin - how to get cropped canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

How to get crop the image using my own button?

I tried to execute this

```
var canvas = $selector.cropper('getCroppedCanvas')
```

but it's returning null value.

Is there a way to get the cropped canvas? And how can I put the cropped canvas data into `<input type="file">` value and send it to PHP?

Answer (score 6):

Your selector should be the HTML container which contains the image:
The Javascript and HTML should be like as mentioned below:

```js
$img = $('#uploader-preview');

$img.cropper('getCroppedCanvas');
var canvaURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'); // it returns the cropped image / canvas
```

```html
<img src="" id="uploader-preview">
```

Send Canvas Image to PHP:

```js
var photo = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');                
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'photo_upload.php',
  data: {
    photo: photo
  }
});

Here's PHP Script
photo_upload.php

<?php
 
 $data = $_POST['photo'];
 list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
 list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
 $data = base64_decode($data);

 mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/photos");

 file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/photos/".time().'.png', $data);
 die;
?>
```

Comment: I guess second line of first snippet should be:

    var canvas = $img.cropper('getCroppedCanvas');

Or where canvas came from?

Answer (score 1):

What is $selector? If it something like this:

```
var $selector = $(".selector");
```

Then you need call getCroppedCanvas() function to jQuery wrapper. Because if you write:

```
var canvas = $selector.cropper('getCroppedCanvas');
```

It calls cropper getCroppedCanvas function to DOM element, not to jQuery element.

Write something like this:

```
var $selector = $(".selector"); 
var canvas = $($selector).cropper('getCroppedCanvas');
```

And it will be work fine. If you want save canvas data as image on server, you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198131/how-to-save-a-html5-canvas-as-image-on-a-server)

Comment: Your concept of jquery objects seems a bit confused. $('body').get(0) == $($('body')).get(0);