# Base 64 png image how to save to server and reuse througout website

Tags: javascript, php, html, server, base64

I'm using avaku http://giocc.com/introducing-avaku-customizing-avatars-with-html5-canvas.html In use-- http://www.giocc.com/sandbox/avaku/.

As you can see from the index.html the images from the left and all its layers get compiled into one .png file at the right.

My main question:

How would I go about saving that image ,that gets compiled into one png, upload it to a server and reuse it (I'm using php and a localhost)
I've searched into a previous thread but it didn't seem to work or perhaps I did it wrong. [How to save a HTML5 Canvas as Image on a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198131/how-to-save-a-html5-canvas-as-image-on-a-server?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**Other questions I have are:**

1. How to set up a store where user can buy clothing?
2. How to let users be able to use/see only clothing/accessories they bought from a store in there wardrobe.
3. How can I divide the different tabs (like hair, shirts,and pants etc ) into drop down's (when hovered or clicked on a tab for example a tab that says hair and all the hair options can pop up underneath)

I've searched for paper dolls since I imagined they had similar code but most sites where dead or only provided drag and drop code.