# Store first frame of html5 video into folder without ffmpeg

Tags: javascript, php

I have a problem with fetching first frame of html5 video. i tried with canvas. here my code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var video = document.getElementById('video');
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
canvas.href = canvas.toDataURL();
canvas.download = "myimg.png";
```

i drawn the result. thats fine. but now my problem is i want to save result( that drawn image) directly into folder. Also i can't able to convert canvas image to URL format using DataURL()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save an HTML5 Canvas as an image on a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198131/how-to-save-an-html5-canvas-as-an-image-on-a-server)

Comment: I can't able to convert the format using  canvas.toDataURL(). It won't work for me

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate why toDataURL ain't working. Do you get any error messages in the console?

Comment: it gives undefined