# How can I send a copy of a user generated png to my backend?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, graphics, request

I am building a site that allows users to create customized graphics and then download them directly from the page.

I am doing this via the user customizing an svg via a javascript powered form which is then made into a PNG before downloading.

However, now I want to store a copy of the png that the user created so that I can display it on the site's home page.  What is the best way to store a copy of the dynamically created graphic?  AJAX? HTTP Request?  Both are very foreign topics to me so I am unsure how to go about it from here.

For reference here is the code that builds the PNG from the svg and then triggers the download for the user.

```
var svg = document.getElementById("bg2");
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

function triggerDownload (imgURI) {
  var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
    view: window,
    bubbles: false,
    cancelable: true
  });
    if(document.getElementById("name").value=="null" || document.getElementById("name").value=="") {
    var un = "MakeAGraphic";
  } else {
    var enteredName = document.getElementById("name").value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "");
    var un = `${enteredName}_MakeAGraphic`
  }
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.setAttribute('download', `${un}.png`);
  a.setAttribute('href', imgURI);
  a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');

  a.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var data = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);
  var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

  var img = new Image();
  var svgBlob = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
  var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

  img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

    var imgURI = canvas
        .toDataURL('image/png')
        .replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');

    triggerDownload(imgURI);
  };

  img.src = url;
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save an HTML5 Canvas as an image on a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198131/how-to-save-an-html5-canvas-as-an-image-on-a-server)

Answer (score 0):

agree to that answer mentioned by @showdev .

Call
*canvas.toBlob(callback, mimeType, qualityArgument);*

then call
*formData.append("an-image", blob);*

then upload *formData* using the AJAX or fetch API.

see the documents at

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Do I need to use the canvas.toBlob method or can I simply utilize my pre-existing line of code turning it into a blob?

var svgBlob = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
  var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);